# T-SQL Group by / Order by + SQL Server Reporting Service Parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

```
select
    Users.UserId
   ,Users.FirstName + ' ' + Users.LastName AS
   ,[Month]
   ,[Day]
   ,x.[Przych]
   ,x.[Wych]
   ,x.[Przych] + [Wych] as [Ogół]
from
   (select
       CaseActionHistory.UserId
       ,month(CaseActionHistory.DateAdded) AS [Month]
       ,day(CaseActionHistory.DateAdded) AS [Day]
       ,sum(case when CaseActionHistory.CaseActionDefinitionId in (14,15,16) then 1 else 0 end) AS [Przych]
      ,sum(case when CaseActionHistory.CaseActionDefinitionId in (20,21,22,23,26) then 1 else 0 end) AS [Wych]
    from CaseActionHistory
    where CaseActionHistory.CaseActionDefinitionId in (14,15,16,20,21,22,23,26)
    group by month(CaseActionHistory.DateAdded),day(CaseActionHistory.DateAdded), CaseActionHistory.UserId
    order by month(CaseActionHistory.DateAdded) DESC,day(CaseActionHistory.DateAdded) DESC
OFFSET 0 rows
) AS x
inner join Users on x.UserId = Users.UserId
```

I'm trying to run out something out of this. My problem is: the results of such query are displayed like this:

```
User    Month    Day    X
User1     7       31    6
User2     7       31    7
User3     7       31    9
User1     7       30    8
User2     7       30    7
User3     7       30    8 
User4     7       31    10
User5     7       31    20
User6     7       31    23
User4     7       30    5
User5     7       30    7
User6     7       30    65
```

So in fact few Users are grouped into small groups which are displayed first, then 2nd group, etc. so I suppose there's a problem either with group by or order by.

As an addition I'd like to ask a question concerning parameters in SQL Server. Out of code below I'd like to set up 3 parameters:

```
User
Month
Day
```

But my problem is that when I set up details of parameter and I run it some values are multiplied. Same user is multiplied few times, same month, same day etc. also report itself is not reacting on any kind of change within parameters.

---

The main idea of a report is to show the number of phone calls done by every employee, each day, every month and to be able to compare results with others.

Calls are splitted into: outgoing and incoming. After every phone call employee adds to system an information regarding what phone call it was and what they managed to do during this phone call.

So in fact we are working on 2 tables in this case:

CaseActionHistory and Users

So the plan was to show the number of phone calls (incoming, outgoing and sum of those) for every day for every person.

Since CaseActionHistory table consits only ID of User which done the action and I'd like to show the person's name (which is placed in Users table obviously).

The problem is that the report should show around 20 Users one by one, so for 31st of June 20 Users one by one, for 30th 20 Users one by one etc, but it shows like 5 Users for 31st, then same Users for 30th, then next 5 Users for 31st etc (link to image showing the situation below)

http://img801.imageshack.us/img801/2088/7blu.png

Columns are:

UserId (to be replaced with UserName) Day Month Incming Outgoing Sum

The rows on the bottom for 31st July should be on the top of the list but they are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow.  A few things:

1. If your data is 'multiplying' may you just do a 'distinct' in your main select statement and determine if it is not your dataset repeating?
2. How are you applying parameters?  They should be predicates and have nothing to do with groupings except indirectly.  You may limit a set by a parameter but it will not affect your grouping directly, generally speaking.
3. What do you want to group by?  Year, Month, (detail)?

SSRS starts out with a data connection (Data Source).  You then apply a Data Set which is a query or proc.  Which you have a query.  You can apply a predicate to the main dataset with a 'where User = @User' or 'where User in (@User)'.  The parameter will automatically be created if you do this in your dataset first with the '@(something)' creating a text parameter of said name.  You see the Built In Fields, Parameters, Images, Data Sources, DataSets in the 'Report Data' view which you will use constantly in SSRS creation with 'Business Intelligence Development Studio'.

So a simple example would be that you want to add a group for the Day to your '(Details)' row.  If you create a 'Table' element from the 'Toolbox' it will only have a single row called Details.  Fill it with your X value and user.  In the 'Design' surface at the bottom you will see 'Row Groups'.  Right click on your 'Details' row and choose add parent group.  Group by 'Day' check 'Add Group Header'.  You now have another row that will be grouping by Day.  You can repeat this process on the newly created group for a group for 'Month' and so and so on.

Comment: My guess is your query is needing a grouping like  'group by UserID' and then to aggregate the data displayed.

Comment: Ok so I managed to do the sorting. Still have a problem with parameters. I used something like this: `where CaseActionHistory.CaseActionDefinitionId in (14,15,16,20,21,22,23,26,24,25,27) and @Month = month(CaseActionHistory.DateAdded) and @User = CaseActionHistory.UserId`. Without seting possible values (they have to be typed manualy), works fine as long as you put something with NULL doesn't put the results at all (for month). For User I created additional data set which takes records from Users table but same stuff as with month - you need to put something to show the results.